# Need to change capitalize python to interpret 3 different types of inputs the SAME with the raw_input function

Tags: python, string, raw-input, capitalize

Wether I enter 1 word, 1 word and 1 word in parenthesis, and 2 words. ie. "American" or "american (grill)" or "american italian" only the first letter in each word will be capitalized.

I have wrote my code

```
wcity = raw_input("Please enter a city ==> ")
print
wtype = raw_input("Please enter a restaurant type ==> ")
print
```

And changed it to:

```
wcity = raw_input("Please enter a city ==> ").capitalize()
print
wtype = raw_input("Please enter a restaurant type ==> ").capitalize()
print
```

I need to change **.capitalize** for **wtype** it so when I input for wtype **EITHER** (not all, only 1 of them at a time)

```
aMERICan
aMerican iTalian 
american (nEw)
```

Python interprets it as

```
American
American Italian    
American (New)
```

- **BUT I need python to read it the same wether its 1 word "aMERICan" or "American (New)"**

any ideas, ive fooled around with upper and lower and those dont work better than the .capitalize

Any ideas?

I can do **.capitalize** as I do in **wcity** because my cities don't have parenthesis with **1** word inside them or 2 words

**My inputs for wcity are not:**

- chicago (troy)
- vegas (reno)
- chicago bronx **(2 words)**

**My inputs for wcity are:**

- chicago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression filter to eliminate the part of the string containing `"(new)"`:

```
import re
def myfilter(x):
    return ' '.join(re.sub(ur'\(\s*[nN][eE][wW]\s*\)','',x).title().split())

wcity = myfilter( raw_input("Please enter a city ==> ") )
print wcity
wtype = myfilter( raw_input("Please enter a restaurant type ==> ") )
print wtype
```

Comment: thanks so much! i ended up solving this last week, he taught us in class

Comment: if you liked the answer and you whant to keep it as accepted you can vote it up and click on the green arrow beside the answer...  ;)